# how to check if a location is on NFS or RAM

Tags: linux, filesystems, nfs

I know if I put file on /dev/shm, then it is put on RAM of the server.

And if I put in my home directory, it is put on NFS.

And i know there is a command to tell if a given location on NFS or maybe RAM, what's that command?

Ex, how can I be sure my home directory is on NFS? I remember by using that command, some prints "NFS" can be seen

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `df` command to show you the directory's mount point:

```
[mrsam@octopus ~]$ df -h .
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md0        178G   32G  137G  19% /home
```

So, my current directory is on a filesystem that's mounted on /dev/md0.

Based on the device that the filesystem is mounted on, you can then figure out if it's a local filesystem, an NFS mount, or something else.

Comment: stupid question, how can I tell whether it is NFS or local filesystem from /dev/md0 ? thanks

Comment: Use Google. /dev/md0 is Linux soft-RAID, a.k.a. local disk. Take a home directory that you know is NFS-mounted, run df, see what it says, and that's how you learn whether something is NFS-mounted, or not.